# Using javascript on asp page to move browser window

Tags: javascript, html

I'm moving from IE to Chrome and have used some standardized scripts on some of my intranet pages which positions the browser window at 50,50 with vbcript window.MoveTo.
Eventhough all info I have found on the net seems to support this command on Chrome, I can't get it to work. Nothing happens when the script is executed in the client.

This is my script which is located between the HEAD and BODY tags.

`<script>
    myWindow = this.window;
    myWindow.moveTo(50, 50);
</script>`

Why does it not work as expected?

Regards
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/moveTo):

> websites can no longer move a browser window in the following cases:
>
> - You can't move a window or tab that wasn’t created by Window.open().
> - You can't move a window or tab when it’s in a window with more than one tab.